# Python Threading Timer - activate function every X seconds

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, python-multithreading

Is there any simple way to activate the thread to fire up the function every X sec, to display some data?

```
def send_data():
    data = "Message from client"
    socket.sendall(data.encode())


write_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_data())
write_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [ischedule](https://github.com/aleksve/ischedule) module - it provides very straightforward syntax for scheduling any given function.

Here's an example straight from the GitHub page:

```
from ischedule import run_loop, schedule


@schedule(interval=0.1)
def task():
    print("Performing a task")


run_loop(return_after=1)
```

The `return_after` param in `run_loop()` is an optional timeout.
Also, in case you're unfamiliar, the `@` syntax is a Python [decorator](https://pythonbasics.org/decorators/).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be this:

```
import time

while True:
    task()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).